# PHPUnit Code coverage not including folders in report

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, code-coverage, pcov

I have a project where I ran phpunit with code coverage on the `./app` folder. This worked fine and the `phpunit.xml` file had this section.

```
    <coverage processUncoveredFiles="true">
        <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </include>
    </coverage>
```

Since then, I changed the structure and made namespaced modules. Now the code coverage does not cover the modules at all. My `phpunit.xml` section looks like this now.

```
    <coverage processUncoveredFiles="true">
        <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">./module/module-one/src</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">./module/module-two/src</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">./module/module-three/src</directory>
        </include>
    </coverage>
```

After this change, only the `./app` files are shown in the report and there is no indication of any other files. Even the report root is `/app`. I have tried several configurations e.g. using only `./module` as the directory, but nothing has worked.

The `phpunit.xml` file is being read, because the generation reacts to changes in the file.

How can I include the rest of the files in the report?

PHPunit version is 9.5.13, XDebug version is 3.0.3, and Code Coverage version is 1.0.8

Comment: Have you find the issue ? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Please check your composer.json that need to autoload each module folders you provided.
2. Please make sure that your Pcov exensions disabled on the first place. `pcov.enabled=0`
   https://github.com/krakjoe/pcov

Comment: If you're using pcov for coverage, another thing to check is setting `pcov.directory` appropriately for your situation. By default it'll look for `src`, `lib`, or `app` in the current working directory. For example `php -dpcov.enabled=1 -dpcov.directory=. -d pcov.exclude='~vendor~' vendor/bin/phpunit ...`